# asp.net Menu control is not highlighting the selected item

Tags: asp.net, menu

I am trying to set the backcolor on the asp.net menu's selected item but it has no effect.

```
 <div id="navepanel" style="float:left;">
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
<StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#D5D9F7" />
<DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#D5D9F7" />

    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="New Chapter" Value="New Chapter" NavigateUrl="~/ChapterManagement/CreateNewChapter.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit Chapter" Value="Edit Chapter" NavigateUrl ="~/ChapterManagement/EditChapter.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Select Chapter" Value="Select Chapter" NavigateUrl ="~/ChapterManagement/SelectChapter.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Add Topics" Value="Add Topics" NavigateUrl ="~/ChapterManagement/AddTopics.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>

    </Items>

</asp:Menu>
```

I am using Chrome currently for the testing purpose. This menu control is on the master page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" StaticDisplayLevels="1"
                Orientation="Horizontal"  DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" >
                    <staticselectedstyle backcolor="LightBlue" />       
                </asp:Menu>
                <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false"  />
```